# Floating menu with hidden submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, floating

So What I want to do is have my main menu to float but at the same time be resizable (window width) I also have a hidden sub menu and I want it to follow the rules of the main menu.

In addition, the main menu doesn't start at the top of the page but as you scroll down I want it to stick to the top edge and rest there.

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/j62FT/)

CSS

```
#menutop {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-spacing: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 65px;
    font-family: 'airship_27regular', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9000;
}

.dropdownwrap {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#dropdown {
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#dropdown:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#CenterMenu {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.insideMenu {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 88px;
    width: 130px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.insideMenu h1 {
    font-family: 'airship_27regular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    word-spacing: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: left;
}

.insideMenu p {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    word-spacing: 1.5px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: rgb(0, 102, 102);
    text-align: left;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT ( What version of jQuery? )

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $('#dropdown').on('click', function () {

        $('.dropdownwrap').slideToggle();

    });

});

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
    var d = document;
    if (d.images) {
        if (!d.MM_p) d.MM_p = new Array();
        var i, j = d.MM_p.length, a = MM_preloadImages.arguments;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0) {
                d.MM_p[j] = new Image;
                d.MM_p[j++].src = a[i];
            }
    }
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
    var i, x, a = document.MM_sr;
    for (i = 0; a && i < a.length && (x = a[i]) && x.oSrc; i++) x.src = x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
    var p, i, x;
    if (!d) d = document;
    if ((p = n.indexOf("?")) > 0 && parent.frames.length) {
        d = parent.frames[n.substring(p + 1)].document;
        n = n.substring(0, p);
    }
    if (!(x = d[n]) && d.all) x = d.all[n];
    for (i = 0; !x && i < d.forms.length; i++) x = d.forms[i][n];
    for (i = 0; !x && d.layers && i < d.layers.length; i++) x = MM_findObj(n, d.layers[i].document);
    if (!x && d.getElementById) x = d.getElementById(n);
    return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
    var i, j = 0, x, a = MM_swapImage.arguments;
    document.MM_sr = new Array;
    for (i = 0; i < (a.length - 2); i += 3)
        if ((x = MM_findObj(a[i])) != null) {
            document.MM_sr[j++] = x;
            if (!x.oSrc) x.oSrc = x.src;
            x.src = a[i + 2];
        }
}

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

HTML ( Fixed HTML format, removed extra tag, added missing tag )

```
<div id="menutop">
    <p>
        <a href="index.html"> ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#" id="dropdown" name="dropdown" title="Click This Button"> WORK</a>
        <a href="contact.html"> CONTACT</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="dropdownwrap">
    <div id="CenterMenu">
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>BRANDING</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="JessWork.html">X20</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">FAUNE DU QC.</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">TIANGLE</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">NAT GEO</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>MULTIMEDIA</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="">SMOKED MEAT</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">CITYSCAPES</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">M. MASON</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>ILLUSTRATION</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="">TUNAS & <br />TRUMPETS</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">PUNCTUATION PAMPHLETS</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>PACKAGING</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="">SPICE OF LIFE</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">PERSONAL<br />PRESS KIT</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>PUBLICATION</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="">JOHN CAGE</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">LEAD</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">SOCIAL ISSUE</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">CALL FESTIVAL</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-sticky-position/index2.html sticky nav

Comment: @user3538186 If you've found a solution for this question please post it or close your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/j62FT/4/

Essentially as you scroll down the page, it detects when the top of the viewport hits the top of the menu and then adds a class of fixed to the menu. This has the effect of docking the menu to the top of the screen. Doing this though meant moving your sub menu into the main menu so it still opened after you scrolled down the page.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    new mainMenu().load();

});

function mainMenu() {

    var thisObj = this,
        menu = $("#menutop"),
        win = $(window),
        pos =  menu.offset().top;

    thisObj.load = function() {

        // Bind slideToggle

        $('#dropdown').on('click', function () {

            $('.dropdownwrap').slideToggle();

        });

        // Set Fixed

        win.on("scroll", function() {    

            if( win.scrollTop() > pos) {
                menu.addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                menu.removeClass("fixed");
            }            
        });        
    }    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menutop">
    <p>
        <a href="index.html"> ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#" id="dropdown" name="dropdown" title="Click This Button"> WORK</a>
        <a href="contact.html"> CONTACT</a>
    </p>

<div class="dropdownwrap">
    <div id="CenterMenu">
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>BRANDING</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="JessWork.html">X20</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">FAUNE DU QC.</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">TIANGLE</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">NAT GEO</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>MULTIMEDIA</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="">SMOKED MEAT</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">CITYSCAPES</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">M. MASON</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>ILLUSTRATION</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="">TUNAS & <br />TRUMPETS</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">PUNCTUATION PAMPHLETS</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>PACKAGING</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="">SPICE OF LIFE</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">PERSONAL<br />PRESS KIT</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="insideMenu">
            <h1>PUBLICATION</h1>
            <p>
                <a href="">JOHN CAGE</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">LEAD</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">SOCIAL ISSUE</a>
                <br />
                <a href="">CALL FESTIVAL</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#menutop {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    word-spacing: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'airship_27regular', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    z-index: 9000;
    background: #ccc;
}
#menutop p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


.dropdownwrap {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#dropdown {
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#dropdown:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#CenterMenu {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.insideMenu {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 88px;
    width: 130px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.insideMenu h1 {
    font-family: 'airship_27regular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    word-spacing: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: left;
}

.insideMenu p {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    word-spacing: 1.5px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: rgb(0, 102, 102);
    text-align: left;
}
```